# Set print extent in demto3D of QGIS diferent than x min, x max, y min, y max

Tags: coordinates, extents, 3d, printing, tools

I have an area that I want to print in 3D. The area has 4 sets of coordinates. I first used a polygon of the area of interest, then cut the DEM of the same area.

I used demto3D from QGIS to generate the `.stl` file for 3D printing. The problem is that, since the tool only allows using 2 set of coordinates (x min, x max, y min, y max) the extent used for the .stl is not valid for 3D printing as there are areas that should not be printed.

I cannot use the extent of any layer as all of them have the same extent `x min`, `x max`, `y min`, `y max` and the "Draw extent" option of the tool only allows drawing a polygon with 2 sets of coordinates. I tried rotating the map but the layer extent rotated as well.

[image]

The coordinates are:

ID) X, Y

1. 814694.0575, 3938294.3278
2. 817343.353, 3940802.3944
3. 823580.744, 3934322.6341
4. 820987.1192, 3931826.0213

Is there a way that I can use the tool and create an .stl file with the extent I need?

Comment: I think you will need to rotate the DEM. Do you know the angle between the horizontal axis and the 4-3 line?

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. I did rotate the DEM but the extent rotated as well.

Comment: Ok, if you know the angle I was asking about, I might write an answer later.

Comment: The angle between the horizonal axis and the line is 44º, approximately. I will try to get the exact degree.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the coordinates of the 1, 2, 3 and 4 points?

Comment: Coordinates included!

Answer (score 3):

You can perform a rotation (and a translation and a scale, if you want), both of the raster and the clipping polygon, using the [PROJ Affine operation](https://proj.org/operations/transformations/affine.html) inside the Warp (for the raster) and Convert format (for the vector) processes in QGIS.

I have created a polygon with the same coordinates in some CRS, downloaded the SRTM elevation model for that location, clipped the DEM and extracted the clipped raster extent in QGIS:

[image: QGIS window with the layers ready to process.]

To calculate the angle of rotation, I used the differences between the Y and X coordinates of points 3 and 4, the quotient of which is the tangent of the angle.

```
dy = 3934322.6341 - 3931826.0213 = 2496.6128
dx = 823580.744 - 820987.1192 = 2593.6248

tan(α) = dy/dx = 0.962595977
α = 43° 54' 29.39"
```

PROJ affine parameters for this case (without translation nor scale) are:

```
s11 = cos(α) = 0.720452303
s12 = sin(α) = 0.69350449
s21 = -sin(α) = -0.69350449
s22 = cos(α) = 0.720452303
```

The PROJ operation can be included as an additional parameter to the Warp process using the `-ct` command option, documented in [gdalwarp](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-ct).
It is not necessary to change any other option (but you can adjust some things, like pixels size or resampling method if you want). Assign the input raster and include the following line as an additional command-line parameter:

`-ct "+proj=affine +s11=0.720452303 +s12=0.69350449 +s21=-0.69350449 +s22=0.720452303"`

[image: Warp process dialog.]

To rotate the clipping polygon the same additional parameter is included in the Convert format process, which is documented in [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-ct):

[image: Convert format process dialog.]

In this way, both the raster and the clipping polygon are rotated. You must zoom in on the layer, since by not doing any translation, the rotation is done around the zero of the CRS.

[image: QGIS window zoomed in to the outputs.]

Now you can clip the raster again so that its extent fits that of the polygon.

Comment: I will try it and let you know. Thanks Gabriel!

Comment: We tried this solution and we had a problem with the rotation. It is not a "perfect" rotation, that is, it is not 0 to de CRS; it is around -1.9º. We think the problem is that QGIS rounds the numbers to one decimal and the difference, even as small as it is, it is not valid for printing.

Comment: The problem may be the rounding of decimal places on my calculator when calculating the rotation angle. QGIS is not involved in any of this process. Try to calculate the rotation angle, sine and cosine, with more decimal places (for the answer it may be useful to show the angle in sexagecimal degrees, but for the calculation decimal degrees or radians may be better).

Comment: We have tried it and we are in the process of checking if it is accurate. At the moment looks pretty good!

Answer (score 1):

To get rotated extensions you have to rotate the map view, in the bottom toolbar of QGIS. DEMto3D keep that rotation to build the model extension[image]

Comment: Thanks Jawensi. The problem with this solution is that QGIS only allows one decimal place and the rotation is not 100% accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Late response, but I would just create the stl using the original layer extents, then trim it as required in meshmixer or similar.